# How can I link the pages when I am adding records to the database

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to add records to the database using laravel. When I click on register, I am redirected to a nee page but I get an error saying page has expired due to inactivity. The record isn't inserted into the database.

The files are as follows:

register.blade.php

```
<form action="/registers" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Full name">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="contact" placeholder="Contact Number">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="secondpass" placeholder="Retype password">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="checkbox icheck">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> I agree to the <a href="#">terms</a>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Register</button>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
  </div>
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/register', 'mainController@register');
Route::post('/registers','mainController@registration');
```

mainController.php

```
 public function register(){
    return view('register');
}

public function registration(Request $request){
    $username = $request->input('username');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $contact = $request->input('contact');
    $password = $request->input('secondpass');

    $data=array("username"=>$username,"email"=>$email,"contact"=>$contact,"password"=>$password);
    DB::table('users')->insert($data);

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the `CRSF` token? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf

Comment: I have added the crsf_token but it still brings the same output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [CSRF token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf) to the form:

```
{{ csrf_field }}
```

In Laravel 5.6+:

```
@csrf
```

Comment: It still doesn't add the record after adding the csrf_token

Comment: @jptl431 well, the original problem was solved because now you're not redirected with the error. If you want help with the new issue, please post the error you now get.

Comment: Thanks. I have found my error. I forgot to add the token and also I had a wrong database query. Solved it